# NetCDF time variable is missing a 'units' attribute

Tags: python, netcdf, time, datetime, xarray

I have NetCDF files whose dates range from Jan 1850 to Dec 2014 (15th of each month). I need to extract data post Jan 1995. I am doing this:

```
start_time = datetime.datetime(1995, 1, 10, 0, 0)
times = DS[0].variables['time']
sdt = dateutil.parser.parse("1995-01-10T00:00:00")
st_idx = netCDF4.date2index(sdt, DS[0].variables['time'].values, select='after')
DS_subset.append(DS[0].variables['zos'][st_idx:, lat_inds_2, lon_inds_2])
```

[image][image]

I am getting this error:

> st_idx = netCDF4.date2index(sdt, DS[0].variables['time'].values,
> select='after')   File "src/cftime/_cftime.pyx", line 679, in
> cftime._cftime.date2index AttributeError: netcdf time variable is
> missing a 'units' attribute